# Data type mismatch exception when executing datagridview adapter fill in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, datagridview, ms-access-2010

I am trying to perform a query from an SQL Query string I found with OleDBDataAdapter so that I may fill the datagridview with the result from the query string. The string is:

```
Dim sqlsearch as string = "select DateField1, DateField2 from TableOne where DateField1 >= '" & CType(StDate, Date) & "' and DateField1 <= '" & CType(EnDate, Date) & "'"
```

I want to display the results of the dates between the start date and end dat. The "StDate" is the start date and the "EnDate" is the end date and theyt get their values from two textboxes (The two textboxes are readonly and get the date string from DateTimePicker controls which use the short date format).

The database fields "DateField1" and "DateField2" also use the same date format (Short). The code I have used to try and populate the datagridview is as follows:

```
Try
        Dim StDate As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim EnDate As String = TextBox2.Text

        Dim sqlsearch As String
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable("TableOne")

        Try
            DBConnas.ConnectionString = ConnStr
            DBConnas.Open()

            sqlsearch = "select DateField1, DateField2 from TableOne where DateField1 >= '" & CType(StDate, Date) & "' and DateField1 <= '" & CType(EnDate, Date) & "'"
            ' Once again we execute the SQL statements against our DataBase
            adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlsearch, DBConnas)
            ' Shows the records and updates the DataGridView
            dt = New DataTable("TableOne")
            adapter.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

            DBConnas.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            DBConnas.Close()
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I get a "Data Type Mismatch In Criteria Expression" exception message when dt has to fill the adapter.

Please help me with this [roblem or help me with a better way of querying with a Date Range in vb.net and MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using octothorphes and a forced format:

```
sqlsearch = "select DateField1, DateField2 from TableOne where DateField1 >= #" & CType(StDate, Date).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "# and DateField1 <= #" & CType(EnDate, Date).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#"
```

Comment: wORKS PERFECTLY. Thank you for the solution. @Gustav

Answer (score 0):

```
  sqlsearch = "select DateField1, DateField2 from TableOne where DateField1 >= '" & StDate.value & "' and DateField1 <= '" & EnDate.value  & "'"
```